# Dual Booting Kali Linux and Ubuntu on encrypted hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

:)

I started using Ubuntu a couple of months ago and I really like it. I have done a little research and would like to try out Kali Linux but also have Ubuntu as a second OS to fall back on.

I am getting a new computer soon and I wanted to dual boot Kali Linux and Ubuntu 14.04 on a fully encrypted hard drive. How would I go about doing this?

Since I will probably have to partition the hard drive to do this, I would also like to know if there is a way to change the size of the partitions later on? The hard drive will be 1TB and I plan on setting Ubuntu up with 200GB and the rest used for Kali Linux, which will be my primary OS. However, if I later decide that I would rather switch back to Ubuntu as my primary, is there a way to resize the partitions? I would prefer not having to reinstall the OS's after I've set them up the way I like them, but if I have to I will.

I have dual booted with Ubuntu before using GParted, but the hard drive wasn't encrypted. This time I would like to have full disk encryption and the ability to dual boot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!